# I performed some wrong operation with /lib, then no software can run in Ubuntu 10.04.

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, libraries

At the beginning I tried to fix the problem of `/lib/ld-linux-so.3:No such file or directory` when I tried to run some dynamically cross-compiled binaries. So I added some shared binaries to `/lib`. I changed or deleted some important files in `/lib`. I know it seems silly.

Now the problem is whenever I want to run an executable binary I get this error:

`Error while loading shared libraries:libgcc-s.so.1:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

I have copied `libgcc-s.so.1` to `/lib` from somewhere else.
Would anyone give some suggestion to fix `/lib`? Something to update or install it again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try booting ubuntu from external media (CD,USB), then mount your root partition in /mnt/root for example. After that try reinstalling the `libgcc1` package, the command should be something like:

```
apt-get --root-directory=/mnt/root install libgcc1
```

This should fix the libgcc problem, but perhaps you will have other problems with other libraries. Repeat this until you have usable apt-get in your real linux, where you can reinstall the other broken libs.

Hint: if you have your linux working or have another ubuntu linux, you may find the package name for each file you need by running:

```
apt-file search /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Hint2: You may find useful the chroot, once you reinstall the missing libraries, you can

```
chroot /mnt/root /bin/sh
```

this way you will be able to see if your linux is working correctly without rebooting to your linux and back to external media in case it's not working.